# Export XLIFF file seems to be missing some .strings and .stringsdict files for localization

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xliff

I am attempting to export XLIFF files for my app. I currently have 2 `.strings` files one from a module and one in the app itself, and one `.stringsdict` file.

When I select the project file, and go to editor > Export for localization only the strings from the first file are included (the one from the other module) in the exported XLIFF file.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure this out.

Just a simple oversight, needed to link these localization files to my project by tapping on this "Locaolize..." button in the right pain

[image]